# How to "reset" the database of Proton CEP

Tags: fiware

I have a written a rule which detects whether a value is out of bounds and creates a new event called "AggregateEfficiencyNotNominal". I have a consumers which notifies of any new "AggregateEfficiencyNotNominal". Unfortunately, each time I receive a notification I not only receive the last "AggregateEfficiencyNotNominal" event, but all the history.

I think this is a temporary issue (due to a no-longer existing "always" temporal context), and that Proton might behave correctly if I reset it's memory. It this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, once a value is out of bounds it should be reported once. It if it reported multiple times, something is wrong with the definitions, either on the level of temporal context or on the level of EPA policies. Anyway, the only way to "reset" the memory is to restart the application